# ~ что значит этот символ в javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
if (~e.origin.indexOf("https://example.com"))
```

Что значит данный символ `~` в этом поле?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/bitwise-operators#spisok-operatorov

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Побитовое отрицание. Аргумент приводится к int32 (приводится к числу, дробная часть отбрасывается, число берётся по модулю 2<sup>32</sup> со знаком, NaN и бесконечности превращаются в 0), после чего все 32 бита инвертируются, давая новое число.

`indexOf` возвращает позицию вхождения или `-1` если вхождения нет. При инветрировании всех битов у числа `-1` получается `0` - ложное значение. А из всех остальных значений (с учётом того, что длина строки не превосходит 2<sup>31</sup>-1) будет получаться ненулевой истинный результат. Т. е. делается проверка, что вхождение есть.